# How should "The dangerous pelican film" be translated?

Tags: traducción

Translate.com gives me "La película pelícano peligroso" but then going the other direction with it gives me "The film pelican dangerous!"

Should it be something like "La película de los pelícanos peligrosos" or...???

Comment: What is the meaning you're trying to convey?  Is a film (movie) on dangerous pelicans, a film titled The Dangerous Pelican, a dangerous film (material) made of pelicans?

Comment: A movie about dangerous pelicans.

Comment: Then you are right, it should be _«la película de los pelícanos peligrosos»_.

Comment: Okay, thanks; if you make it an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: LOL, I can't believed ,The dangerous Pelican ?, what movie have it's name, the palican eating the heads of the people, on the final of the film some superkillerpelicanhero(skph) kill the pelican boss, and humanity live happy forever and ever.  And yeah in spanish his traslation is, "La pelicula de los Pelicanos Peligrosos", or, "Los peligrosos pelicanos hacen una pelicula", "Los pelicanos se vuelven un peligro para la humanidad",...LOL...

Comment: Believe me, this film will be the most magnificent ever produced; it will be both critically acclaimed and enthusiastically received by the common rabble!

Comment: Unfortunately, only in Spanish, though; in English it will doubtless lose its cachet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What translate.com attempts to give you is the translation of “the *Dangerous Pelican* film” (a movie titled “Dangerous Pelican”), which whit proper punctuation and capitalization would be *«**la película “Pelícano peligroso”**»*.

If this is a movie about dangerous pelicans (or in particular about some kind of dangerous pelican), a better translation is *«**la película de los pelícanos peligrosos**»* or *«**la película del pelícano peligroso**»*.  The plural is more common in Spanish although the singular is okay when refering to a whole species or group.